# Yii2 unique validation error: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I followed the exact same process mentioned on [Yii2 Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation), but I am getting Array to string conversion error on AJAX validation.

**Scenario:** Enable AJAX validation in SignUp form including server side validation like email unique validation.

**Changes made in view**

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-signup',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]); ?>
```

**Changes made in controller**

```
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

** SignUp Widget **

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components;

use Yii;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use common\models\User;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * SignUpFormWidget is a widget that provides user signup functionality.
 */
class SignUpFormWidget extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @var string the widget title. Defaults to 'Register'.
     */
    public $title='Register';
    /**
     * @var boolean whether the widget is visible. Defaults to true.
     */
    public $visible = true;

    public function run()
    {
        if($this->visible) {
            $model = new SignupForm();

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                    if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                        return $this->goHome();
                    }
                }
            }

            return $this->render('signUpWidget', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

`[error][yii\base\ErrorException:8] exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Array to string conversion' \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php:107`

I have tried using `json_encode($error)`, but its reloading page, I cannot reload the page since register form is on header under hidden div. I have created SignUpFormWidget which extends Widget.

Please suggest, what I am missing here?

Comment: please give your controller all code

Comment: Try commenting out the 'Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;'

Comment: @vishu: I have updated question with the Widget code as requested.

Comment: @Coz: I tried, same error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because `Widget::run()` method is expecting to return a string. `ActiveFrom::validate()` returns an array. As @DoubleH suggested above, you need to re-write your code as

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

   Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
   return yii\helpers\Json::encode(\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model));
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you so much. Now it's returning error message. But for some reason, the error message isn't getting displayed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MohitBhansali It may be that you haven't told Yii where to display errrors on your form. Try adding `echo $form->errorSummary();` at the top of the form. The error should display there.

Answer (score 3):

Update Your Controller code as

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

   Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
   return yii\helpers\Json::encode(\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model));
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's returning error message now. But for some reason, the error message doesn't render below each fields. Any idea regarding same?

Comment: Check Your model rules

Answer (score 1):

You are using this `Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;`

it means your are getting value in  array .So try to fetch value from array then validate it , or just comment it as says in comment . You Can't  validate array as string so it is giving you error .